# How To Use Cloc On Ubuntu

Tags: command-line

I'm a Ubuntu novice and I'm trying to figure out how to use cloc to count lines of code in a directory.

https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc

I think I got it installed correctly using: sudo apt-get install cloc

However, I cannot figure out how to get it to scan a directory. The directory is here: Documents/My Work/Company/HostMedics/hm_site-updated

Although when I type in the terminal: cloc Documents/My Work/Company/HostMedics/hm_site-updated

I think this is the way I'm using the terminal. It seems to stop at My Work.

What do I type to get it to scan a directory?

Comment: Take the path in quotes `""`. The problem is the space in `My Work`.